# How do I get key and cert from --capath

Tags: node.js, security, https, openssl, ssl-certificate

With OpenSSL and adding CA have `curl -X GET https://someserver.com -I --capath /etc/ssl/certs/` working fine. `curl -X GET https://someserver.com -I --cacert /etc/ssl/certs/someserver.pem` works as well.

I would like to make the same call with node.js https.request()

I've tried `node --use-openssl-ca app.js` with SSL_CERT_DIR set to /etc/ssl/certs/ - didn't help.

Tried:

```
const https = require('https');
const fs = require('fs');

const options = {
          hostname: 'someserver.com',
          port: 443,
          path: '/',
          method: 'GET',
          ca: fs.readFileSync('/etc/ssl/certs/someserver.pem')
}

const req = https.request(options, res => {
          console.log(`statusCode: ${res.statusCode}`)

          res.on('data', d => {
                      process.stdout.write(d)
                    })
})

req.on('error', error => {
          console.error(error)
})

req.end()
```

Error: write EPROTO 140249139050368:error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/record/rec_layer_s3.c:1544:SSL alert number 40

Thank you.

Comment: alert 40 is NOT due to certificate validation; the certificate may not even have been received. The best approach is to check the server log(s) to see what it thinks the problem is. Or try commandline `openssl s_client -connect host:443` and if OpenSSL version below 1.1.1 add `-servername host`; if that also fails get network traces preferably with wireshark and look for differences.

Comment: What key? Those `curl` commands don't return keys. Only certificates.

Comment: Sure curl does not return the key, but CA is valid as curl works perfectly. Specifying the same cacert to nodejs does not help.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 openssl s_client -connect someserver.com:443
CONNECTED(00000003)

Comment: That's pretty incredible; `s_client` without `-quiet` should output _lots_ of information unless the server hangs, which you know this one doesn't. But try adding `-debug` to make it even noisier. Oh, and one more thing (shades of Columbo): do you have any proxy settings? curl will use them, but I don't think nodejs will and openssl definitely won't.

Comment: Sure, output is way larger. It is a lot of information. Including server certs, ciphers and etc etc. Just don't understand how it might help. My node.js understanding is I need to provide the right CA file as https call options, as I did it for curl. But it does not help.

Answer (score 0):

Just rebuild node.js with openssl support. So now I use the same libs as curl.
Thank you everyone